# How many galaxies have been discovered?

Tags: galaxy

I know Andromeda is our nearest galaxy. But how many known galaxies have been discovered and what are they?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, the nearest galaxy to ours is not Andromeda, according to the NASA based page ["The Nearest Galaxies"](http://heasarc.nasa.gov/docs/cosmic/nearest_galaxy_info.html), it was until recently considered to be the [Canis Major Dwarf Galaxy](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/C/Canis+Major+Dwarf) at approximately 42,000 light years away.  However, recently, there is suggestion that the closer [Omega Centauri Globular Cluster](http://mcdonaldobservatory.org/news/releases/2008/0402.html) may be a disrupted dwarf galaxy ([Another source](http://blackholes.stardate.org/directory/factsheet.php?p=omega-centauri)).

Now, in answer to your other query of how many galaxies there are - there is a global project called [Galaxy Zoo](http://www.galaxyzoo.org/) which is attempting to catalogue and classify all observed galaxies, so far, according to the [Galaxy Zoo for astronomers](http://www.galaxyzoo.org/#/astronomers) page, thus far they have

> - the entire Sloan Digital Sky Survey spectroscopic sample and all existing Hubble Space Telescope surveys (around 1.5 million galaxies in total).

*Pictured: The Hubble Ultra-Deep Field which contains over 10,000 objects, the majority of which are galaxies. The image is only a bit over 3 arcminutes across--a tiny sliver of the sky.*

[image: Hubble Ultra Deep Field]

Answer (score 12):

If you want to know the number of `spectroscopically confirmed` galaxies then the number given by UV-D is roughly correct.

But the actual number of galaxies that have been observed is order of magnitudes larger.

The case I know is the Sloan Digital Sky Survey 3 (SDSS3):
they observed about a third of the sky using five different filters between optical and near infrared. Of all the objects detected `208,478,448` are galaxies. And of those 1.5 to 2 millions will have the spectrum measured by mid next year. 
[More info here](http://www.sdss3.org/dr8/scope.php)

To these number you have to add the galaxies observed by surveys in different areas of the sky, deeper that SDSS (which means that they can seen fainter and/or more fare away objects).

By the way, if memory does not fail me, estimates gives about 10^10 galaxies in the observed universe